# Get APK / AAB install size

Tags: android, gradle

Using `apkanalyzer` it is possible to find out a multitude of properties from a generated APK / AAB, such as file size, compare with another APK to get the file size delta, etc.

Using this tool I have created several Gradle tasks to:

- get specific dependencies sizes, and sum them to gain insight how big a SDK is;
- get download size of APK, using `apkanalyzer`;
- get comparative file size of APK, using `apkanalyzer`, comparatively to an empty app to gain insight of SDK size;

Now, what I really need is to find out is actual install size of an APK. Meaning the storage amount the APK takes once installed on a device. I have found that `apkanalyzer` does not provide a solution for this, and don't have the knowledge how to approach this. I don't want to do this manually, but rather has to be automated. Preferably via a Gradle task.

So: how to automate calculating the INSTALL size of an APK preferably using Gradle?

Comment: The "install size" of an APK is indeterminate. It will vary by OS version at minimum, and I cannot rule out it varying by device model (due to manufacturer tinkering). Depending on your definition of "install size of an APK", it might also vary by time, as AOT and similar optimizers kick in. For an AAB (as mentioned in your question title), the "install size" will vary by device model and by user settings, as the AAB results in an arbitrary number of APKs representing pieces of your app to be installed.

Comment: That makes sense. It doesn't have to be very precise. Let's assume there's a reference emulated device, Pixel 4, Android 12 whereupon the APK is installed. I would like to know via gradle task --> adb --> installed APK size. Meanwhile I found this solution https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220442/obtaining-app-storage-details-via-adb?newreg=c04f94376d9b4c659b7d08fc2aa36df7 but doesn't work for me: `line 23: [: 1: unary operator expected`

Comment: You could translate that shell script into Groovy/Kotlin for use in a Gradle task. Note that it assumes that the app is installed -- does that meet your needs? Usually, when I think of a Gradle task, it is for stuff preceding app installation.

Comment: You are correct. However, this is part of CI and we want to figure out our SDK sizes per release. The final gradle task would be to 1) install on reference device, which in this case is an emulated device, 2) determine install size, and lastly 3) include this information in my generated report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed my own answer.

1. Create an AVD using e.g.: `echo no | avdmanager create avd -n <name> -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" -f`
2. Run AVD: `emulator -avd <name>`
3. Be sure to run adbd in root: `adb root`. This is important to retrieve package information.
4. Install APK on AVD: `adb push <absolute_path_to_apk>`
5. Get code path of installed APK: `echo $(cut -d "=" -f2- <<< $(adb shell dumpsys package $packageName | grep codePath))`
6. Use code path value from step 5 to get install size from APK: `adb shell du ${codePath} -h | awk 'FNR == 3' | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}'` This returns a string value representing the install size of APK on reference device in Mb.